# Keep submenu expanded when parent or children are active

Tags: routes, navigation

I have a two-tiered menu system using the [Nice menus](https://drupal.org/project/nice_menus) module, which I've adapted to run horizontally with the children beneath the top level, as in the following menu.

> Home - About - **Adopt an animal** - Events - Get Involved - Contact
>
> Cats - Dogs - Small Animals - Birds

At the moment, the second tier is showing only on hover of the parent. After clicking through or landing on a page I need the children to be expanded when their parent or siblings are active and I'd like the parent to be highlighted as active in this case too - so in this example if I'm on Adopt an animal page or dogs / small animals / birds  then I need that expanded.

I'm not sure where to even start on this, I don't really want to hack it by duplicating false second tier menus and using context or block to display them on certain pages because I need to be able to hand over the menu administration so the integrity is important. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

[Menu Trail By Path](https://drupal.org/project/menu_trail_by_path) sets the active-trail on menu items according to the current url.

For example if you are at yoursite.com/blog/category1/article1
Menu Items with these paths will get the active-trail class on them and expand accordingly.

```
blog
blog/category1
blog/category1/article1
```

This is particularly useful if you want a lot of nodes to appear as children of certain nodes / taxonomy term / views / referenced nodes / etc, but do not want to add them all to the menu. eg. hundreds of blog articles.

Comment: Thanks very much. With some well-structured pages and aliases this solves the active trail issue. It doesn't seem to play ball with nice-menus, but does with the core Primary Menu. Although my menu doesn't switch on hover at the moment, this has got me 90% of the way there. Many thanks.